# Share a view between UIViewControllers? Second viewController "steals" view from first?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am experiencing this behavior: I have a UIViewController UIView which I want to share  between 2 or more UIViewControllers.

First I instance the shared UIViewController in AppDelegate with:

```
SharedViewController *sharedViewController = [[SharedViewController alloc] init];
```

Then, when I am instancing the new UIViewController I add the shared view controller view:

```
ViewController1 *viewController1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
```

and inside it I add the shared view controller view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:sharedViewController.view];
}
```

**This works fine, as long as a second view controller - i.e. viewController2 - does the same thing, then viewController2 gets the view and viewController1 gets nothing!**

I applied a workaround, placing this in viewWillAppear and it seems to work, but I am afraid I am adding the same view one onto another multiple times, isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about it. Each UIView can have only one superview. Once it is added to another superview, it will first be removed from its previous superview

Comment: I see, so it is well known? Only 1 UIViewController at a time for a UIView?

Comment: Nothing related to UIViewController here. It's just a UIView and its superview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear {
    [self.view addSubview:sharedViewController.view];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear {
    [sharedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This should work. 
But are you sure it has to be a shared UIViewController, if you only use the view? Why not just a shared UIView?

Comment: I added the ViewController to handle autorotation without the mess of notifications as this is for the iPad. Thanks, your idea is good, but it is only improving my workaround, I am trying to understand why this is happening.

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi because a view can have only one super view and it cannot be a part of more than one view hierarchy